# MySQL UNION query syntax

Tags: mysql, syntax, union

I have two tables that I want to query and merge based on a `category_id`.

My events table has a column called `event_category_id` that creates a relationship between the event and it's category.  The value is an int.

In my categories table I have a column called `category_id` which is what I want to match on and replace the int value with the varchar value of `category_name`.

What's my syntax?  Thanks for the help!

`categories`
`CREATE TABLE`wp_wild_dbem_categories`(`
category_id`int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,`
category_name`tinytext NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`category_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1`

`events`
`CREATE TABLE`wp_wild_dbem_events`(`
event_id`mediumint(9) NOT NULL auto_increment,`
event_author`mediumint(9) default NULL,`
event_name`tinytext NOT NULL,`
event_start_time`time NOT NULL default '00:00:00',`
event_end_time`time NOT NULL default '00:00:00',`
event_start_date`date NOT NULL default '0000-00-00',`
event_end_date`date default NULL,`
event_notes`text,`
event_rsvp`tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',`
event_seats`tinyint(4) default NULL,`
event_contactperson_id`mediumint(9) default NULL,`
location_id`mediumint(9) NOT NULL default '0',`
recurrence_id`mediumint(9) default NULL,`
event_category_id`int(11) default NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY`event_id`(`event_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=26 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1`

Comment: please post your table structures as output from `CREATE TABLE tablename`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you want a `UNION`.  You probably want something like this:

```
SELECT e.event_id, e.other_field, c.category_name
FROM events e JOIN categories c ON (e.category_id=c.category_id)
WHERE some_condition;
```

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect, and you're right, I wanted JOIN.  Cheers!

Comment: I wish I could give you more points here, I just reference this again for another project!  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from events e join categories c on (c.category_id=e.event_category_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not UNION but JOIN if I understood correctly

```
SELECT c.category_name, e.* FROM events e JOIN categories c ON (c.category_id = e.event_category_id);
```